# How to add shimmer animation in layer list (Need to add it before start activity as launcher Style background) is it possible?

Tags: android

I'm setting image drawable in layerlist for view image to before start activity. So I set the drawable to style and that style set to launcher. I need to add to animation for that image. is it possible?

````
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="AppTheme">
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/startup_drawable</item>
</style> 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Please add this to your build.gradle file

```
// Gradle dependency on Shimmer for Android
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
}
```

Now in your layout where you have that ImageView

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
     ...(your complex view here)...
</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

And in the Activity where you have the ImageView please put a reference for this ShimmerLayout

```
ShimmerFrameLayout container =
  (ShimmerFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
container.startShimmer(); // If auto-start is set to false
```

For more info please visit [here](https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/)

Hope this helps you out. Let me know

Comment: Thankz for your answer. i already implement inside activity layout xml. but now i need use before load activity. <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/startup_drawable</item> using that code o already added image. but i don't know how to animate it.

Comment: post the activity layout.xml